# Redirect custom Spree Admin upon visiting /admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have defined custom role for admin `editor`, when the `editor` logs in to admin panel, he is redirected to `admin_products_path`, But if `editor` is already logged in, how to redirect it to `admin_products_path` upon visiting `/admin`

Update:
Spree v2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to override [admin_root_redirect_path](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.2/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/root_controller.rb#L12-L14) with some logic based upon if the admin is an editor or not.

Something like:

```
def admin_root_redirect_path
  if spree_current_user.editor?
    spree.admin_products_path
  else
    spree.admin_orders_path
  end
end
```

Comment: there is no `Root Controller` and `admin_root_redirect_path` in `spree v2.3.2`